# Bootstrap 4 navigation over body content on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, bootstrap-4, mobile-safari

This is my navigation code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
            <img width="150" height="60" src="/image-files/logo-gerard.svg" alt="Gerard">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li>...</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
body{ 
    padding-top: 70px; 
}
```

It works fine on desktop PC. But on my iPhone (IOS, Safari browser) I have a problem, because navigation overlaps the body content. It looks like that body padding-top setting in CSS is ignored (whatever number I enter, there is no change).

Anybody has an idea what am I doing wrong? Is it a bug?

Here is the live example: http://gerard.xn--reitve-ckb.si/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add and work bootstrap.js code for good show in any resolution

Answer (score 0):

It overlaps on all kind of devices, not only on iPhone. To fix the issue, increase `padding-top` of  body

`height` of your `nav` is `70px`, and it has `8px` padding top and bottom. You need to set `padding-top` of `body` to `86px = (70 + (2 * 8 ))`. I recommend you to set it to `90px`. `4px` won't make a big difference.

## Update

Padding is not ignored as you in the picture. It works as expected.

[image]

Comment: Padding is ignored, regardless of size.

Comment: @gdolenc Padding is not ignored. It seems that it works as expected.

Comment: Actually it is ignored. If I check it on responsimulator as you did, it shows ok. But if I check it with real iPhone (I use iPhone 7), the padding is ignored.